# Sharing Intent shows old extras in WhatsApp

Tags: android, share-intent, android-intent-chooser

Guys i need help i aam facing a very strange problem and I would like to hear your opinion i added a share button to share images.
I used

```
Intent intent = new Intent ();
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity (Intent.createChooser (intent,"Share Using...."));
```

and it is working perfectly except for one thing if i choose the picture to share then pressed the share button and choose to share via whatsapp or G+ the application loads and the post is created with the chosen image if i backpressed i go back to my app then if i try to share another image and choose whatsapp or g+ both keep showing the old image in the new post and here comes the strange part if i post or send the image the new image is sent to the receipent and not the old image shown in the post. .... any help would be appreciated by the way i have tried using all flags with the intent but the problem persists 
﻿

Comment: did you try this: Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND) ?

Comment: Yes I tried it but it seems that it has no effect

Comment: Would you please post the caller class of these lines of code? (activity or fragment)

Comment: It is an activity with a recyclerview and a share button the chooser intent is called as a response to the button click

Comment: @dEv_tO_bE I'm also facing the same problem. did you find the solution?

Comment: @sujith Did you find any solution for this? I also facing same problem in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a new Intent every time you want to post a *new* value, or clear the current object for that matter.

Can you also elaborate on this one, i didn't quite get what you meant:

> if i try to share any other image whatsapp and g+ keep showing the old image in the new post and here comes the strange part if i post or send the image the new image is sent to the receipent

Comment: Please refer to the post i edited the part you mentioned and hope it is clear now